# DTDs not getting resolved by hibernate

Tags: hibernate, dtd

My application has lots of `cfg` and `hbm` files. I am getting error in loading them.
The issue identified is with DTDs.

The original Doc type would be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

But with this I get error

```
Could not parse the configuration file... filename
```

After some googling, I downloaded this `dtd` and mapped it like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "file:///C://hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Now it is working for files where this is done.

But I can't change each and every file as the number is very large.

On the posts across the net, I found some users faced this issue when they are offline.
But I have stable internet connection, and still facing the issue.

I doubt that the issue lies with the jar file used. I am using `hibernate3.jar version 3.2.5`

Please help.

Comment: *****Could not parse the configuration file***** Can you please post the exact error or exception !! I think its problem with the jar only or the link given in the definition > http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd

Comment: Can you post your configuration file's code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with jar indeed. The file was correct, but its placement caused the problem.

In eclipse project classpath, moving the jar from bootstrap to user entities worked in my case.

Thanks a lot for your help.